# How to keep folders expanded in VSCode?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, expand

I would like to expand all folders inside a folder in VSCode - any suggestions.

I tried manually expanding them all and after that saving the workspace but that didn't do anything - I want to keep the `src` folder fully expanded even after reopening the application.

Answer (score 14):

follow this steps on your VSCode worked for me

**File > Preference > Settings and disable "explorer.compactFolders".**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Explorer. Under the View menu select Explorer. A sidebar appears on the left side of the main VScode window. Displayed there are all the files and folders in whatever folder you chose. Open folders in the main folder will display are the files in that folder and will remain that way until you close the folder.